# UI alternative for selecting taxonomies in Crafter Studio

Tags: crafter-cms

The online document and blueprint demo of Crafter Studio shows using the checkbox-group control for author to select taxonomies. I want to repurpose this feature to support article tagging like Alfresco and Liferay. However, I am dealing with close to 200 tags, making the checkbox-group control a bad UI. Is there an alternative control better suited for large number of taxonomies?

[Content Targeting](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/targeting.html?highlight=taxonomy)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you may consider a node selector connected to a browse / search experience where tags are objects.

Alternatively you can build your own custom form control and plug it in using our plugin framework.
https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/plugins/studio/form-control-plugins.html